# How to measure the Euclidean distance between each evaluation point and the closest reference point in a 2-D problem?

Tags: function-construction

I would like to measure the euclidean distance between each evaluation point and the closest reference point in a 2-D problem. 
Attached my reference and evaluation points to have a look at the inputs.

[image]

Comment: Look up `Nearest`.